# Rolling a die $n$ times, how do you calculate the Variance of the number of results that appear atleast once?

Tags: probability-theory, variance

I can find the expected value of the number of results that appear atleast once.
I need to either find the expected value of that number squared or the probability of having $k$ results appear atleast once.  and then use $Var=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]$

I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 3):

For $k=1,2,3,4,5,6$ let $B_{k}$ take value $1$ if face $k$ appears
at least once and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Now observe that $B:=\sum_{k=1}^{6}B_{k}$ equals the number of faces that appear at least once.

Here:$$\mathsf{Var}\left(B\right)=\mathsf{Cov}\left(B,B\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{6}\sum_{j=1}^{6}\mathsf{Cov}\left(B_{i},B_{j}\right)=6\mathsf{Cov}\left(B_{1},B_{1}\right)+30\mathsf{Cov}\left(B_{1},B_{2}\right)=$$$$6\mathsf{Var}B_{1}+30\mathsf{Cov}\left(B_{1},B_{2}\right)$$

Can you find $\mathsf{Var}B_1$ and $\mathsf{Cov}(B_1,B_2)$ yourself?

Comment: How did you go from the first row to =6Cov(B1,B1)+30Cov(B1,B2)

Comment: There are $36$ covariances $\mathsf{Cov}(B_i,B_j)$. For $6$ of them we have $i=j$ and they are all equal so all take value $\mathsf{Cov}(B_1,B_1)$. The other $30$ with $i\neq j$ also are equal so all take value $\mathsf{Cov}(B_1,B_2)$.

Comment: I see now that the was a typo in my answer. Not both indices are $i $. They are distnct: $i $ and $j $. Repaired now.  Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $X$ be the number of numbers that appear at least once. Obviously, $X$ takes on values in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Calculate, if you have not already done so, $\mathbb{P}(X=i)$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,6$. Calculate $$\mathbb{E}X^2=\sum_{i=1}^6 i^2 \mathbb{P}(X=i).$$
Since you already know $\mathbb{E}X$, then you can calculate the variance as follows:
$$\operatorname{Var}X=\mathbb{E}X^2-(\mathbb{E}X)^2.$$

Comment: Yes, I am having trouble calculating the  P(X=i) for all i=1,2,…,6.   Do you mind helping me? I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Pr(one particular number appearing at least once)=1-Pr(that number never appears)=1-(5/6)^n.

Comment: This requires calculation of the $P(X=i)$. Fortunately that can be avoided.